# Unable to install NGINX, Missing dependancies

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, nginx, dependencies

Edited, see other post for more.

Comment: welcome to U&L please add the content of your `sources.list` , it appear you have a mixed sources trusty and xenial

Comment: Added it just now.

Comment: the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` please

Comment: Added  cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* && sebas, I added "$ sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger trusty main'" & then ran $ sudo apt-get install nginx-extras passenger

Comment: Remove the xenial repositories from `/etc/apt/sources.list/` files. Then run `apt update` and try installing nginx again.

Comment: I've removed all of them, and now i'm receiving the following error, `root@server:~# sudo apt-get install nginx
 nginx : Depends: nginx-extras (>= 1:1.12.1-8.5.1.8~xenial1) but it is not going to be installed Depends: nginx-extras (< 1:1.12.1-8.5.1.8~xenial1.1~) but it is not going to be installed
`

Comment: Ok. `apt-cache policy nginx nginx-extras`. In the question, please. Please put all relevant information in the question.

Answer (score 3):

You have a mixed package from Trusty and Xenial

```
deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger xenial main
deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger xenial main
```

Backup all sources.list under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` then generate a new sources.list from [Ubuntu Sources List Generator](https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/) including the `main` , `Restricted` and `Universe` repo with their security updates

The [nginx package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/nginx) is available on the main repository you don't need to add a new sources.

Then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge nginx*
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

Comment: Done, it gives the following. `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nginx : Depends: nginx-extras (>= 1:1.12.1-8.5.1.8~trusty1) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: nginx-extras (< 1:1.12.1-8.5.1.8~trusty1.1~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
`

Comment: @Zacharin Updates in question, not in comments, please.

Answer (score 0):

One command after the other. `sudo apt-get clean` Cleares apt-cache.
The next 2 let dpkg and apt forget  existing available info

```
sudo dpkg --clear-avail 

sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt install nginx
```